# Clarification on this problem about unitary equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be unitarily equivalent $n \times n$ matrices.
>
> a) Prove that $\operatorname{tr}(A\cdot A) = \operatorname{tr}(B \cdot B)$.
> b) Use a) to prove that $$\sum_{j,k=1}^{n} |A_{j,k}|^2 = \sum_{j,k=1}^n |B_{j,k}|^2 .$$

Is part b of saying that for unitarily equivalent matrix, if you fix a row, the sum of the modulus squared of each component is equal?

Initially, I thought the indexes were referring to the diagonal of the matrix, but I found an example where that is not true, so I assume we are only varying the k, while j remains fixed.

Comment: You’re varying $j$ and $k$, i.e the sum of the squares of the modulus of all entries in $A$ is equal to the sum of the squares of the modulus of all the entries in $B$

Comment: ok thanks, that makes more sense

Comment: Please refrain from using images instead of text. To use MathJax, see here:https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation